# Signing git commits on a remote machine

Tags: git, ssh, digital-signature, remote-server

I'm doing development on a remote, headless, shared, machine (call it `shared`) over SSH using nvim. When I want to submit my changes, I have to raise a github pull request with SSH-signed commits. Because the machine is shared, I don't want to put my SSH key onto it.

Further, the shared machine has special setup that means I can't develop locally.

The repo is large.

My current workflow involves having a local clone of the repo (call it `local`) with a git remote for the shared machine and once I have commits I want to PR:

- pull commits from `shared` to `local`
- signing locally by rewriting history
- pushing the result to my github fork (another git remote, call it `gh-fork`) for the PR process.

Then if the PR process requires that I add follow up commits or that I do squashing, then have to go back to the shared machine and:

- `git fetch gh-fork`
- `git reset --hard gh-fork/thebranch` # to get the signed commits
- add changes and check it all still works (or squash).
- get the follow-up changes to `local` by pulling or fetch+resetting from `shared`.
- sign again
- push to `gh-fork`

My question is a bit vague and open-ended. How can I streamline this?

I think there are two sub-problems:

- automating signing on the remote: if there's a way to get the raw data out of git that needs to be signed, i could write a little daemon that transfers the result to `local` for automated signing (with confirmation, like a button click, to avoid abuse), and send the result back to `shared` and update the repo with the result.
- How to `git push` the signed result to a SSH remote (i.e. `git@github.com/...`) from `shared` without `shared` holding the SSH key.

I appreciate that this is a very niche problem, but I wonder if someone has tackled a similar problem before?

Solutions I considered and didn't like:

- remote filesystems (sshfs was unreliable in my experience)
- rsync/unison (I get confused with what is where and if git does a `git gc` it can cause a full and lengthy resync of `.git`)
- distant.vim (I've never managed to get it working)
- ssh agent forwarding (insecure)

Comment: "Because the machine is shared, I don't want to put my SSH key onto it." why? you do not trust the root user of the server ? other regular users won't be able to see your private key.

Comment: You do realize that you can make your agent require confirmation on your local machine for each signature, right?  That means you can forward the agent without worrying about it being misused.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I would also like to know the answer

Comment: I haven't found a good solution to date,